# C# - Does an Else Counterpart to the Null Conditional exist?

Tags: c#

The shorthand for accessing a reference only when it isn't null is fantastic.

```
var someReference = null;
someReference?.doSomethingIfItIsntNull();
```

What's itching me is the else counterpart of this. Do something else if it is null.

```
someReference?: elseDoSomethingElse();
```

In Java we have the

```
Optional.ofNullable(someReference)
    .ifPresentOrElse(
           sr -> sr.doSomethingIfItIsntNull(), 
           doSomethingElse());
```

Currently I only know of this method:

```
if (someReference == null)
   elseDoSomethingElse()
```

Am I missing something or does this feature not yet exist?

Comment: In my opinion, `if (someReference != null) someReference.DoSomethingIfItIsntNull(); else DoSomethingElse();` is way more readable than that `Optional` stuff in your Java example.  But if you really want it,  you could trivially write that `Optional` class yourself in c#.

Comment: @KirkWoll or, pick one of the existing implementations like [`Functional.Maybe`](https://github.com/AndreyTsvetkov/Functional.Maybe)

Comment: Oh yeah, the Java example is not to be confused as a more readable method. It's more of "here's another language that has a built in implementation of what I'm looking for, so it must be at least somewhat useful to people".

Answer (score -2):

You mean this?

```
someReference?.doSomethingIfItIsntNull() ?? elseDoSomethingElse();
```

Edit: works only with methods that return value

Example https://dotnetfiddle.net/Lse62l

Comment: The OP is using statements, and this won't compile as a statement (i.e. if you add a semicolon at the end).

Comment: @KirkWoll I don't get why you think this wont compile (but im sure im missing something obvious): https://dotnetfiddle.net/KuddGW

Comment: @Jamiec, that example is passing the _expression_ to `Console.WriteLine`, a completely different situation.

Comment: This does not work if `doSomethingIfItIsntNull` returns void because `??` checks, if the returned value of `doSomethingIfItIsntNull` is null, not if `someReference` is null.

Comment: @KirkWoll yep, thanks. I had not thought of that

Comment: @mamen yes, my bad, I edit comment and add example

Comment: Unfortunately the null coalescing operator converts the line to an assignment operation.